# Force language in URL. If URL has no language, redirect basing on browser language

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just translated my website. For SEO reasons (to avoid duplicated content) i want EVERY URL to have the language in it. For instance, `www.racebooking.net/page.php` must become `www.racebooking.net/en/page.php`. The `/en/` part will be, then, converted into `?lang=en`.

Moreover, the user must have the possibility to choose the preferred language when browsing the website.

The logic i'm trying to implement is the following:

- IF the URL is `racebooking.net/en/page.html`, simply go to
  `page.html?lang=en` no matter which language is my browser
- IF the URL is `racebooking.net/it/page.html`, simply go to
  `page.html?lang=it` no matter which language is my browser
- IF the URL is `racebooking.net/page.html`, check browser language. If
  Italian, transform the url into `racebooking.net/it/page.html` and go
  to `page.html?lang=it`, in any other case transform the url into
  `racebooking.net/en/page.html` and go to `page.html?lang=en`

I wrote this htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/[en|it]{1,1}/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /it/%1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/[en|it]{1,1}/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But nothing's happening...it is not detecting that `/en/` or `/it/` is missing! Looks like the first RewriteCond is not happening...

Moreover, it looks like getting in conflict with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(en|it)\/(.*)$ $2\?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

any idea?

**EDIT**
After a long discussion, @anubhava solved the problem! His solution works perfectly.
So, i edited my question to make it more helpful for visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is wrong esp. this part `[en|it]` which basically matches letters `e, n, | , i, t` since it is a character class.

Try these rules instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

# always www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# redirect first visitors basing on their language or redirect if language not specified
# in URL. If italian, redirect to italian
# if lang is Italian use it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

# otherwise use English
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

# populate ?lang query parameter
RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but i am getting Internal Server Error!

Comment: There was a typo, I jut fixed it. Also do you have any other rewrite rule OR any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: Yes actually i have many rules! Your rule looks good, but i am still getting Server Error...BTW i identified a couple rules that may be in conflict...because i have a Rule which transforms urls with `/en/` into urls with `?lang=en` Here is the htaccess portion with the conflict: http://pastebin.com/sEJ6qBDx can you see where's the conflict and how to fix it?

Comment: May i know purpose of last rule: `RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` ?

Comment: Also are `/en/` and `/it/` real directories?

Comment: That's a good question! Nope, `/en/` and `/it/` are not subdirectories! The purpose of the rule you're asking is to transform URLS with `/en/` into URLS with `?lang=en`. My translation system is simply based on the GET parameter `lang`. I.E. if `$_GET['lang']=="en"` the page is translated in English.. To avoid ugly URLS with parameters, i decided to insert the language into the url. I point always to the same file, no matter what language i'm browsing! That's why i wrote this rule

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43149/discussion-between-anubhava-and-alberto-fontana)